# Test for drive presence in an Excel 2007 macro before saving

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro to save files in Excel 2007. I know less than nothing about VB programming, but I was able to put together the macro below from internet searches that works, enabling me to save a given file to each of several drives.

My problem is that if the drive is not plugged in, the macro crashes. I've tried for several days to find the correct syntax to include an `If..Then` statement that would tell the macro to skip a line for saving the file to a given drive if the drive isn't found and continue to on to save the file to the next drive.

I'd envision putting such a statement prior to each instruction. I've tried unsuccessfully to incorporate the post by Christos Samaras (1/23/14) as well as numerous others, all to no avail. If someone would be so kind as to edit my macro to include syntax to either follow the save instruction if the drive is present or continue to the next instruction (to save the file on the next drive) if the specified drive is absent, I'd really appreciate it.

Understand that I'm dumb as the proverbial post, so showing me a sample that I can just cut and paste would be really really appreciated.

The save macro that works when all drives are present is:

```
Sub SaveFile()
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Tmpfiles\macrotest.XLSM", FileFormat:=52 ' 52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = xlsm (with macro's in 2007-2016)
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\Chris\OneDrive\Documents\Tmpfiles\macrotest.XLSM", FileFormat:=52 ' 52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = xlsm (with macro's in 2007-2016) 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "\\LAPTOP-G0BUU3L4\l\Documents\Tmpfiles\macrotest.XLSM", FileFormat:=52 ' 52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = xlsm (with macro's in 2007-2016)
End Sub
```

Comment: Do some research on the [VBA FileSystemObject](https://www.google.ca/search?q=FileSystemObject&rlz=1C1CHZL_enCA733CA733&oq=FileSystemObject&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: To expand on what @Jeeped wrote, you want to examine the different properties of the Drives collection which, itself, is a property of the filesystemobject.  That will give you the names and paths of the available drives, and also, importantly whether they are ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a path exist, you can use [`Dir`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278779.aspx) function:

```
If Dir("C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Tmpfiles\", vbDirectory) > "" Then 
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Tmpfiles\macrotest.XLSM", 52
End If
```

or the Windows Scripting FileSystemObject [`FolderExists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xc78d8d(v=vs.84).aspx) method:

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If .FolderExists("\\LAPTOP-G0BUU3L4\l\Documents\Tmpfiles\") Then 
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "\\LAPTOP-G0BUU3L4\l\Documents\Tmpfiles\macrotest.XLSM", 52
    End If
End With
```

---

The lazy alternative could be to ignore all errors, but it is not recommended in case there are other errors that you need to be aware of:

```
Sub SaveFile()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Tmpfiles\macrotest.XLSM", FileFormat:=52 ' 52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = xlsm (with macro's in 2007-2016)
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\Chris\OneDrive\Documents\Tmpfiles\macrotest.XLSM", FileFormat:=52 ' 52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = xlsm (with macro's in 2007-2016) 
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "\\LAPTOP-G0BUU3L4\l\Documents\Tmpfiles\macrotest.XLSM", FileFormat:=52 ' 52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = xlsm (with macro's in 2007-2016)

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Slai; this works whether or not external drives are present but hangs (Bad File Name) if the networked laptop is turned off. Excerpt from macro constrained by character limit (original has 4 drives) is:   Sub FinalSaveTest()
If Dir("C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Tmpfiles\", vbDirectory) > "" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Tmpfiles\macrotest.XLSM", 52
End If
If Dir("\\LAPTOP-G0BUU3L4\l\Documents\Tmpfiles", vbDirectory) > "" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "\\LAPTOP-G0BUU3L4\l\Documents\Tmpfiles\macrotest.XLSM", 52
End If
End Sub   Any idea why laptop fails?

Comment: @ChrisK. Not sure as I can't reproduce it. My guess is that it scans your whole Network to find it. You can try the `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").FileExists` http://p2p.wrox.com/access-vba/55874-check-if-file-exists-network.html

Comment: Slai, Thanks again; really appreciate your help. Just as before, works w/laptop on but gives Error 400 when off. Not sure if syntax is right. Can you check it? Thanks.   Sub FinalSaveTestMod() Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If objFSO.FileExists("\\LAPTOP-G0BUU3L4\l\Documents\Tmpfiles\macrotestMod.XLSM") > "" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "\\LAPTOP-G0BUU3L4\l\Documents\Tmpfiles\macrotestMod.XLSM", 52
End If
If Dir("W:\Chris\Documents\Tmpfiles", vbDirectory) > "" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "W:\Chris\Documents\Tmpfiles\macrotestMod.XLSM", 52
End If
End Sub

Comment: @ChrisK. check the example in the link. FileExists returns True or False so no need for the `> ""` part

Comment: Slai - I warned you I was dumb as a post. Eliminating >"" (sorry; don't even know how to highlight in blue) as you said made everything work fine (finally). Thanks to you, I now have a macro to save files between networked computers and external drives whether or not any one is present. I literally couldn't have done it without you. Thank you so much, Chris

Comment: @ChrisK. you can click on the help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) below Add Comment for examples. The http://stackoverflow.com/tour might be a bit helpful too.

Comment: @ChrisK. I gave the wrong method `FileExists` instead of `FolderExists`, so I updated my answer. You can accept an answer by clicking on the check next to it if it answers your question.

Comment: Slai - Thanks for the more general case of testing for a folder rather than a file. For my case, FileExists works fine if I include the name of the file. Apparently I could eliminate the filename and just test for a folder with FolderExists. That may prove helpful for future macros.